# Sublime Text 2, disable Build output panel/Console automatic scrolling

Tags: console, terminal, sublimetext2, output, sublimetext

Apparently everytime a script returns a new line the Build panel/Console on ST2 scrolls to the bottom, which is good so we can always see the latest output information, however when having huge stacks of information with long history it is natural that before a process finished you may want to scroll back and debug the information print before.

Since ST2 always scrolls to the bottom when a new line is inserted into the console, this becomes impossible to achieve.

My question is if is there any way to disable this 'automatic scrolling' for new lines on the build output panel or if somehow it is possible to make it behave just like terminal, where it will only continuing to scroll if your cursor or scroll location is already on the latest item and it becomes inactive as soon as you scroll up.

I hope that makes sense.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turns out I was dumb enough to not find out that by *double-clicking* the console panel it will then stop the scrolling and let me navigate through it. once I scroll again to the bottom, it continues from there.

Comment: I have the exact opposite problem. I did what you now said, and want it to continue scrolling automatically. Any idea how?

Comment: Found the answer. Simply use Page Down until you hit the end of the output, and it will continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably sure that this is hardcoded in, but I can be certain since I'm not Jon Skinner :) Most "consoles" act like this, continuously streaming the information as it is collected. Terminal emulators often include a "scroll on output" option to modify this behavior, but in my experience I haven't found anything like this in ST2 or ST3. If your programs are generating the output, you can always sprinkle in statements like `print "=========="` or something similar to break up the output somewhat, and perhaps give you an idea of where you are when you scroll back through.